# Built apk contains unneeded resources

Tags: android, gradle

Having an issue where the apk being generated by our Gradle build contains a bunch of unnecessary files inside a `test/resources` directory

Our application build gradle contains several local module dependencies which are built as android libraries.

I know there is `packagingOptions` field in Gradle but you can't exclude directories as far as I can tell.  Excluding each file isn't an option.  Anyway, I would like to know the root cause for this.

Application gradle build:

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/android_application.gradle"

dependencies {
    compile project(':local-lib1')
    //... etc
    compile project(':local-libN')

    testCompile libraries['junit']
 }

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

And android_application.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion android_sdk_version
    buildToolsVersion android_build_tools_version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion android_min_sdk_version
        targetSdkVersion android_target_sdk_version
    }

    buildTypes {

    }
}
```

All modules are structured like so:

```
module
|
--AndroidManifest.xml
--build.gradle
--assets/
--res/
--src
  |
  -- main/
  |  |
  |  --java/
  |  --resources/
  |
  -- test/
     |
     --java/
     --resources/
```

Why are `test/resources` being included in apk? How can I exclude them?

*Edit* (to show lib gradle):

Example lib gradle:

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/android_library.gradle"


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    // ...etc external deps

    // test deps
    testCompile libraries['logback-classic']
    testCompile libraries['junit']
    testCompile libraries['mockito-core']
    // etc...
}

android {
    packagingOptions { 
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' 
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' 
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}
```

android_library gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion android_sdk_version
    buildToolsVersion android_build_tools_version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion android_min_sdk_version
        targetSdkVersion android_target_sdk_version
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

        }
    }
}
```

I am building with `gradlew.bat -x test build`

The `test/resources` included in the apk contains all the files in the corresponding `test/resources` for each lib.  The size of directory (uncompressed) is 10mb so adds unreasonable amount to size of overall apk.

Comment: What is inside `test/resources/`? How is your APK size affected?
Please show the `build.gradle` files of your `local-lib1` etc, as there might be external dependencies, which include the directories.

Comment: Edited to address your questions, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've solved the issue.

I had in app build.gradle and each library build.gradle:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

Changed to

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        }
    }
}
```

I guess gradle was taking every resources dir under `src/` and merging them into one - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging

Answer (score 2):

Try the [resource shrinking](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking). As per Google Documentation: "The Gradle build system for Android supports

> resource shrinking": the automatic removal of resources that are
>   unused, at build time, in the packaged app. In addition to removing
>   resources in your project that are not actually needed at runtime,
>   **this also removes resources from libraries you are depending** on if they are not actually needed by your application

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        test {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried adding this to my android_application gradle (debug instead of test) but complained about proguard.  Then added proguard line `proguardFiles ...` but complained about missing file `proguard-rules.pro`.  Created empty file with this name then got a bunch of errors "Can't find referenced class..."

Comment: Try -keep class com.yourpackage.** { *; } -dontwarn com.yourpackage.** on the proguard file to avoid the problems with the reference class. Of course, check what is the referenced class it is complaining about, then modify "yourpackage" accordingly.

Comment: Added for each occurrence which made the warnings disappear, thanks.  Then got `X depends on program class org.xmlpull.Y` etc so added `-ignorewarnings`.  The build went further and generated the apk, but only removed about ~1.5mb of stuff.  But the `test/resources` directory was still there :(

Comment: Well, then it is another problem going on, shrinkResources did the job. Gradle shows how much data it was able to shrink, you should then check if those resources are not actually being used somewhere. Unfortunately, that is the further I can go to help you with my knowledge. I am brand this on this topic too.